# Android, Gradle : RetroLambda not working

Tags: android, gradle, lambda, dex, retrolambda

I am working on an Android application and I came up with RetroLambda tool, with which I can use Lambda expressions in Android app(So much win!!).

Unfortunately it is not working. I am posting my Gradle files for app and overall. Kindly let me know what I am doing wrong. Thanks a lot.

Build.gradle (Module : app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.6.0'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.6.0'
    compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:1.0.1.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-core:1.0.1.RELEASE'
    compile ('org.springframework.android:spring-android-auth:1.0.1.RELEASE'){
        exclude group :'org.springframework', module: 'commons-logging'
        exclude group :'org.springframework', module: 'spring-core'
        exclude group :'org.springframework', module: 'spring-web'
    }
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
    compile 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.9'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.0.1'
}




android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "myapp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
    productFlavors {
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }

}
```

Build.gradle (Module : projectName)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
        classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.2.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Error log :

```
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72221Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportMediarouterV72200Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42221Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAds750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalytics750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppindexing750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppinvite750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppstate750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesCast750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesDrive750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesFitness750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGames750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGcm750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIdentity750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesNearby750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPanorama750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPlus750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesSafetynet750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWallet750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWearable750Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareIoReactivexRxandroid101Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJava
Note: /home/akshay/AndroidStudioProjects/app/app/src/main/java/myapp/com/app/Service/RestaurantServiceImpl.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources
:app:preDexDebug
:app:dexDebug
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:","position":{},"original":"UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536","position":{},"original":"com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$6.updateIndex(DexMerger.java:502)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$6.updateIndex(DexMerger.java:502)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$IdMerger.mergeSorted(DexMerger.java:277)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$IdMerger.mergeSorted(DexMerger.java:277)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeMethodIds(DexMerger.java:491)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeMethodIds(DexMerger.java:491)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:168)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:168)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"SIMPLE","text":"\tat com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)","position":{},"original":"\tat com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)"}


 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 8.888 secs
```

I am right now running in Emulator. I hope that is not the problem. Thanks a lot.

Comment: `compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }`?

Comment: @tibo : Should I change that to 8?

Comment: @tibo : Did that, didn't help.

Comment: did you setup all the envs as described [here](https://hakanyamanyar.wordpress.com/2014/07/08/using-java-8-lambda-expressions-in-android-developer-tools/)?

Comment: @tibo : Without retrolambda everything works fine. I did the 3 steps mentioned on the Github page. I have the support library as you can see from the build.gradle files.

Comment: "com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536" - it looks like you're hitting the 64k method limit. There are plenty of questions dealing with that already

Comment: Looks like you compile your project with java 8 - this doesn't work. Go to project structure > SDK location and make sure you've set it to Java 7 or Java 6. Leave sourceCompatibility in your gradle script as it is with Java 8 so AndroidStudio recognizes the Java 8 syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You can check my project. I'm using retrolambda. But to build the project you need to define java8 path on your system.
https://github.com/JenyaKirmiza/GithubClient

Answer (score 0):

You may apply the plugin in your app's build.gradle (instead of the root project). The other thing you should check, is your dependencies has java 8 written classes or not. If so, be aware that the plugin only works on your current project (classes), and have nothing to do with classes inside dependencies. If you want to retrolambda those dependencies, you may unpack them somewhere and apply the plugin on.